# How to make a loop with multiple columns in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file with three columns (ID number, x, y)

```
ifile.txt
1      32.2    21.4
4      33.2    43.5
5      21.3    45.6
12     22.3    32.5
32     21.5    56.3
43     33.4    23.4
44     23.3    22.3
55     22.5    32.4
```

I would like to make a loop over column 2 and 3 so that is will read like

```
for x=32.2 and y=21.4; do execute a fortran program
for x=33.2 and y=43.5; do execute the same program
and so on
```

Though my following script is working, but I need it in an efficient way.

```
s1=1   #serial number
s2=$(wc -l < ifile.txt)   #total number to be loop
while [ $s1 -le $s2 ]
do
x=$(awk 'NR=='$s1' {print $2}' ifile.txt)
y=$(awk 'NR=='$s1' {print $3}' ifile.txt)
cat << EOF > myprog.f
...
take value of x and y
...
EOF
ifort myprog.f
./a.out
(( s1++ ))
done
```

Kindly Note: myprog.f is written within a cat program. for example,

```
cat << EOF > myprog.f
....
....
take value of x and y
....
....
EOF
```

Comment: How does `xyz` relate to shell variables `$x` and `$y`, and if `xy` refers to these shell variables, what does `z` refer to?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No, here xy does not refer those variables. I have changed it. Thank you.

Comment: So you expect `$x` and `$y` to be _environment_ variables that `myprog.f` will be able to read? Is `$s1` of relevance, or is it only used to drive the loop?

Comment: yes, $s1 is not important here. It is used only to drive the loop.

Comment: Does your update mean you're _(re-)writing_ your Fortran program's source code in each iteration of the loop, compiling it with `ifort`, and then executing it? Why would you not _statically_ compile a program that takes _arguments_?

Comment: Yes. I am rewriting the source code in each iteration of the loop. I have no other idea. Can you please suggest if there is any other short and convenient way. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know Fortran, but this may get you started: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html#GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT

Answer (score 6):

Simple way to read a file in bash is

```
while read -r _ x y; do
    echo "x is $x, y is $y"
    # your Fortran code execution
done < ifile.txt
x is 32.2, y is 21.4
x is 33.2, y is 43.5
x is 21.3, y is 45.6
x is 22.3, y is 32.5
x is 21.5, y is 56.3
x is 33.4, y is 23.4
x is 23.3, y is 22.3
x is 22.5, y is 32.4
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create Fortran source code in each loop iteration with the loop variables baked into the source code, compiling it, and then invoking it, which is quite inefficient.

Instead, you should create a Fortan program *once*, and have it accept *arguments*.
(I don't know Fortran, and you haven't stated a specific compiler, but perhaps [this GNU Fortran documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html#GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT) will get you started.)

Assuming you have such a program and its path is `./a.out`, you can invoke `awk` combined with `xargs` as follows, passing the 2nd (`$2`) and 3rd (`$3`) fields as arguments:

```
awk '{ print $2, $3 }' file | xargs -n 2 ./a.out
```

- `awk '{ print $2, $3 }'` prints the 2nd and 3rd whitespace-separated field from each input line, separated by a space.
- `xargs -n 2` takes pairs of values from `awk`'s output and invokes `./a.out` with each pair as arguments. (This approach relies on the values having no embedded whitespace, which is the case here.)